# How to force re-render function component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to re-render my function component when one of the function's variable is changed. Importantly this variable does not comes with props.

I am building a simple registration form with Material UI and React 16.8. It comes with the hooks API that I am trying to use. The thing is that I would like to re-render my component when result of the input field validation changed.

```
export default function Register(props) {
 let emailError = false;
 const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
 const validateEmail = (email) => {
    if(email) {
      emailError = false;
    } else {
      emailError = true; // How to force re-render if email is not valid? 
    }
 } 

 return (<div>
            <TextField
                  error={emailError}
                  variant="outlined"
                  required
                  fullWidth
                  id="email"
                  label="Email Address"
                  onKeyUp={(ev) => validateEmail(ev.target.value)}
                  onChange={(ev) => setEmail(ev.target.value)}
                  name="email"
                  autoComplete="email"
                  aria-describedby="email-error-text"
                />
   </div>);
}
```

Here you can find source code of this component: https://github.com/przemek-nowicki/auth-react-and-redux/blob/master/src/componnents/Register.js

Comment: In your invalid case just do `setEmail('');`?

Comment: Don't use a local variable, that gets reset every time the component re-renders anyway. Use setState again.

Comment: welcome to React, please read more about antipatterns

Answer (score 1):

You should probably store the error bool in the state as well.

```js
const [emailError, setEmailError] = useState(false);
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  setEmailError(!email);
}, [email]);
```

Comment: The key take away is that you need to store your error as state then update state when your input changes.

Comment: The key take away is that updating the state forces a re-render.

Comment: This is definitely a good solution, but it would be helpful to explain for the OP what useEffect is doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this,

```
const [emailError, setEmailError] = useState(false);
 const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
 const validateEmail = (email) => {
    if(email) {
      setEmailError(false);
    } else {
      setEmailError(true); 
    }
 }
```